# LXML failed to install on Plone 4.3 64-bit (MS Windows)

Tags: plone, lxml

Been asked to update my answer in correct format - Question then Answer.

```
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml
copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml
```

then generates

```
running build_ext
building 'lxml.etree' extension
**error: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat**
An error occurred when trying to install lxml 2.3.6. Look above this message for
 any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
Installing.
  Getting section zeo.
  Initializing part zeo.
  Getting distribution for 'lxml==2.3.6'.
Error: Couldn't install: lxml 2.3.6
```

Answer (score 2):

http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/How-do-I-get-LDAP-working-with-Plone-4-td5510664.html

Plone › Installation, Setup, Upgrades

How do I get LXML working with Plone 4.3 64-bit

Buildout failed with false/positive pointing to and asking for vcvarsall.bat

With thanks for original posting by Didakus - Sep 08, 2010 re: LDAP

Found some help in the Plone chat room. Here's what I did to get LXML working.

1. Install Python (v 2.7.4) on drive C:\
2. Install lxml-3.2.1.win-amd64-py2.7 (C:\Python27\lib\site-packages)
3. Install/Have Installed Plone 4.3 with the installer (C:\Plone43)
4. Edit buildout.cfg and pin [ver] lxml = 3.2.1
5. Create a new folder called lxml.3.2.1-py2.7.egg in C:\Plone43\eggs\
6. Copy C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lxml-3.2.1-py2.7.egg-info to C:\Plone43\eggs\lxml-3.2.1-py2.7.egg\ and rename to EGG-INFO
7. Also copy the lxml folder in C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ to C:\Plone43\eggs\lxml-3.2.1-py2.7.egg\
8. Next copy:
   folder: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lxml-3.2.1-py2.7.egg-info
   folder: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lxml
   to C:\Plone43\python\Lib\site-packages
9. Start commandbox and run bin\buildout

It compiles for me.

Comment: I have some questions about some parts of the instructions:
4. just pin it at the end? Is [ver] different from [versions]?
8. I'm a bit unsure about what to do here, so should I copy the egg-info folder AND the lxml folder into site-packages?

I've done everything you stated above, but buildout is still downloading and trying to install lxml... I did it with python 2.6, might that be an issue?

Comment: There is no connection to Windows - it is all Python related.
Have a look at link above which refers to LDAP using Python 2.6
Egg and Python should be same version 2.6 or 2.7 - 
I'm an end-user and have only interpreted a solution that I found.
Rgds

Comment: Thank you very much! I was finally able to run buildout without errors. I installed Python 2.7.4 and added lxml = 3.2.1 to [versions] instead of [ver].

Comment: Have just loaded Plone 4.3.1 and lxml loaded normally - version pinned to lxml = 2.3