# can't install Plone add-on

Tags: plone, lxml, multilingual, egg

I'm trying to install plone.app.multilingual and as far as I can see the installation goes well, but the add-on wont appear in the Add-ons list on my site.

cmd:

```
C:\Plone43>bin\buildout.exe
Getting distribution for 'lxml==2.3.6'.
Building lxml version 2.3.6.
Building without Cython.
ERROR: 'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

Using build configuration of libxslt
error: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
An error occurred when trying to install lxml 2.3.6. Look above this message for
 any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
  Installing.
  Getting section zeo.
  Initializing part zeo.
  Getting distribution for 'lxml==2.3.6'.
Error: Couldn't install: lxml 2.3.6
*************** PICKED VERSIONS ****************
[versions]
archetypes.multilingual = 1.1
plone.app.multilingual = 1.1
plone.multilingual = 1.1
plone.multilingualbehavior = 1.1

*************** /PICKED VERSIONS ***************

C:\Plone43>bin\instance.exe stop
Stopping Windows Service "Zope1810026918".

C:\Plone43>bin\instance.exe start
Starting Windows Service "Zope1810026918".
```

lxml installation is failing, is there a possibility that it is the cause?

I've tried several different configuarions on my buildout.cfg and this is my most recent one (only the parts that concern the eggs):

```
[buildout]
...
eggs = 
   Pillow
   Plone
   plone.app.iterate
   plone.app.openid
   Products.CMFPlacefulWorkflow
   plone.app.multilingual [archetypes]
   plone.app.multilingual [dexterity]

zcml =
    plone.app.multilingual
```

All help is appreciated! I've been stuck on this for a while now and I see this as a last resort...

Comment: If `lxml` isn't installing then any other changes to your buildout will *also* not apply. Is `plone.app.multilingual` listed at all in `bin/instance`?

Comment: Nope. Well, that explains things... Why does buildout imply that it installed successfully? I interpret <Picked versions> ... </picked versions> as successful installations.

Comment: It *doesn't* imply it installed successfully: *Error: Couldn't install: lxml 2.3.6*.

Comment: I've googled that lxml issue a bit and to me it seems like it's a no go on Windows. I installed it manually, so I'm wondering if it is possible to turn off the lxml installation in the buildout? Is my only option to install Ubuntu?

Comment: Someone else posted this: [LXML failed to install on Plone 4.3 64-bit (MS Windows)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17323734)

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't mean that buildout implied that lxml installed correctly, just that everything between the <Picked versions> tags did.

Comment: I take it that the 'picked versions' output is what is giving you the impression there was a successful buildout run. That part does not signify anything worked, just what versions were used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martijn Pieters pointed out the issue was lxml not installing correctly. He posted a link to a question that explains how to solve the issue:

[LXML failed to install on Plone 4.3 64-bit (MS Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323734/lxml-failed-to-install-on-plone-4-3-64-bit-ms-windows)